# Directive template value not updating

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-directive

I'm setting up a directive like so (timeout function just as a demo):

```
app.directive('timeRange', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            sliderId: "@sliderId",
        },
        template:   '<div id="{{sliderId}}"></div>'+
                    '<p>From: <span>{{fromVal}}</span>'+
                        '<span style="float:right;">{{toVal}}</span><span style="float:right;">To: </span>'+
                    '</p>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            scope.sliderId = 'NewId';
            scope.fromVal = '06:00';
            scope.toVal = '17:00';

            setTimeout(function(){
                scope.fromVal = 'Hello';
                log("Changed");
            }, 2000);
        },
    };
});
```

When the timeout function runs, the HTML doesn't update, the value stays at `06:00`. How do I get the template to update when the variable does? Do I need to somehow link it in the `scope` section where I link the attribute?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The only issue I can see with your example is that you are using `setTimeout` instead of the `$timeout` service. Any time you change angular or scope variables this way you are going to have to manually call `$scope.$apply()` which is what the `$timeout` service does for you. The following code works better then:

```
app.directive('timeRange', function ($timeout) {
    return {
        restrict: 'A',
        scope: {
            sliderId: "@sliderId",
        },
        template:   '<div id="{{sliderId}}"></div>'+
                    '<p>From: <span>{{fromVal}}</span>'+
                        '<span style="float:right;">{{toVal}}</span><span style="float:right;">To: </span>'+
                    '</p>',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {

            scope.sliderId = 'NewId';
            scope.fromVal = '08:00';
            scope.toVal = '17:00';

            $timeout(function(){
                scope.fromVal = 'Hello';
                console.log("Changed");
            }, 2000);
        },
    };
});
```

Note the injection of `$timeout` and the way it is used.

**See This In Plunker:** http://plnkr.co/edit/KlRAeg6cVhehw2EhWzCK?p=preview

**Fixing The Original...**

The fixed original code looks like (just a snippet):

```
setTimeout(function(){
    scope.fromVal = 'Hello';
    scope.$apply();
    console.log("Changed");
}, 2000);
```

Best of luck!

Comment: Thanks for that, I was unaware of the $timeout service. The actually code doesn't use a timeout, but calling scope.$apply updates the variables nicely :).

Comment: @TomHart Be careful adding when calling `scope.$apply()`. Sooner or later you are going to call `scope.$apply()` when an apply is already in progress - often because angular is running an apply for you. You'll probably get something like a `digest already in progress` for this. Anyways, glad I could help!

Comment: @drew_w what should I use then? `scope.$apply()` is more straightforward than `$timeout`. Will I get the digest error for both cases?